# How frequently can the Tooth and Claw Tattoo be used?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

The [Tooth and Claw Tattoo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2219) does not mention any frequency for the usage, it seems like you can use it as often as you want.

This is very good, probably too good to be true. I did not find any [official errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) to this, however.

Is this a mistake, or intentional?

Comment: FWIW, I confirmed that the text is the same in my PDF of Treasure Vault. I don't think it's enough to constitute an answer, but at least it confirms that it's not just a mistake on Nethys' part (which I've see on rare occasion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That is the RAW

There is no doubt that is how it was written in the original text, and how it is presented on the official online reference site, Archives of Nethys. Tooth and Claw Tattoo is not addressed in the errata.

### That is also "too good to be true"

Paizo did some CYA in their 2nd edition printing, including guidance that if rules are ["too good to be true"](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) they should be adjudicated in a way consistent with what makes more sense. This specifically is called out relating to ambiguous rules, but I believe the sentiment applies.

> If one version is too good to be true, it probably is. If a rule seems to have wording with problematic repercussions or doesn’t work as intended, work with your group to find a good solution, rather than just playing with the rule as printed.

Nearly every other magic item, and certainly every magic item granting a spell effect equivalent to the level of the item, only allow for one use per day. I'm confident that, when they get to it, TaCT will be errata'd as such, and is how I will be running all my games.